# Toggle between CSS style insertion using jquery based on keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text field and an anchor tag field.

If the text field is not empty then I add CSS attributes to the anchor tag.

I need to revert to the previous style if the text field is emptied.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-cloud-upload"></i>
        <label for="">File upload</label>
        <?php if ($announcements_details['file']!='') { ?>
        <a id="anchor" href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>/documents/<?php echo $announcements_details['file'] ; ?>' target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">
            <?php echo $announcements_details['file'] ; ?>
        </a>

        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>
        <input type="file" id="captionfile" name="captionfile" value="<?php echo $announcements_details['file'] ; ?>">
        <?php } else { ?>
            <input type="file" id="captionfile" name="captionfile" value="">
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#captionurl").keyup(function () {
    $("#captionfile").attr("disabled", CheckInputs());
    $('#anchor').css({
        'pointer-events': 'none', 
        'cursor': 'default', 
        'color': '#91969e' 
    });

    function Checkmultiple() {
        var value = $.trim($("#url1").val());
        if (value.length != 0) {
            valid = true;
        } else {
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }
});
```

Comment: show us your html

Comment: You call `CheckInputs()` but the function you show is called `Checkmultiple`.

Comment: @Utkanos-Edited my question

Comment: please add more information, from your post it is not clear what is captionurl and captionfile.

Kindly add your html file for more clearance

Comment: @NARGISPARWEEN-added html

Comment: @VimalS Just FYI, I'm adding back your HTML to the question as it might have been accidentally removed during someone else's edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML template

```
<div class="parent">
    <input type="text" id="mytextfield" class="basic"/>
    <a href="#" onclick="doAction()" />
</div>
```

Javascript Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var inputElem = $('#mytextfield');
   inputElem.keyup(function() {
        var input= $(this);
        if(input.val()){
        input.addClass('modified');
        input.removeClass('basic');
      }else{
        input.addClass('basic');
        input.removeClass('modified');
      }
   });
});
```

CSS Code

```
input{
  outline:none;
}
.basic{
  border:2px solid #d2d2d2;
}
.modified{
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

[Check jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5tBaX/60/)

Comment: @Arun Redhu-Anyway that fiddle got something i need.:-)

Answer (score -1):

jQuery `.css()` function just adds new css entries those have higher priority than ones in css file. If you don't want to create two classes `.basic` and `.modified`, you can reset css properties to default by using:

```js
if($('#your_text_field').val() == ""){
     $('#anchor').css({'pointer-events': '', 'cursor': '', 'color': '' });
}
```

This code checks if your text field is empty. It should be put in keyup function of text field. Setting any css property to empty ("") with jQuery, defaults any modifications made by `jQuery`.